# Output tooltip if click on tool

Tags: extjs, tooltip

Hello I have a window with tools. I have the tool: 'help', and when clicking on it I want it to output a tooltip with text from my HTML file, but actually it shows alert('Help'), and it doesn't output from the file:

```
tools: [
    {
        type: 'refresh',
        name: 'refresh',
        tooltip: 'reload'
    },
    {
        type: 'help',
        handler: function (event, toolEl, panel) {
            alert('Help');

            var tooltips = [{
                    target: 'tip1',
                    html: 'A very simple tooltip'
                }, {
                    target: 'ajax-tip',
                    width: 200,
                    autoLoad: {url: '/help/note/help.html'},
                    dismissDelay: 15000 // auto hide after 15 seconds
                },
            ];

            Ext.each(tooltips, function (config) {
                Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', config);
            });
        },
    }
]
```

This picture shows what I actually want:

[image]

Comment: Which version of ExtJs you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the html file in an Ajay request from server and then create the tooltip in the success callback.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '/help/note/help.html',
  success: function(response){
    // in the success callback you get the html text in the response.responseText
    // and then you can create a tooltip with the content of it
  }
});
```

So you can do the following in the callback

```
var html = response.responseText;
var tooltip = {
                target: 'ajax-tip',
                width: 200,
                html: html,
                dismissDelay: 15000 // auto hide after 15 seconds
            };
```

The full code should be

```
{
    type: 'help',
    handler: function (event, toolEl, panel) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/help/note/help.html',
            success: function (response) {
                var html = response.responseText;
                var tooltip = {
                    target: 'ajax-tip',
                    width: 200,
                    html: html,
                    dismissDelay: 15000 // auto hide after 15 seconds
                };
                Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', tooltip);
            }
        });
    }
}
```